# Reactのstateが更新されない

Tags: reactjs

## やりたいこと

Reactを使ったWebアプリのフロントエンド部分で、ユーザーがformに入力した値でstateを更新したい。

## 状況

ユーザーがformに入力してもsubmitを押してもstateが更新されない。
`useState`を別のstateの中に入れたことが原因と推測していますが、解決策が分かりません。

## ディレクトリ構成

```
front
├── node_modules
│   └── ...
├── public
│   └── ...
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
├── src
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── Form.tsx
│   │   └── Route.tsx
│   ├── App.tsx
│   ├── consts.ts
│   ├── index.tsx
│   ├── types.tsx
│   └── ...
└── ...
```

## コード

`App.tsx`

```tsx
import { useState } from "react"
import Form from "./components/Form";
import { TimeSpecType, ViaListType, RouteType, QueryType, modesType } from "./types";
import { NUM_ROUTES } from "./consts";

function App() {
    const [viaCount, setViaCount] = useState<number>(0);

    const [index, setIndex] = useState<number | null>(null);
    const [origin, setOrigin] = useState<string>("");
    const [destination, setDestination] = useState<string>("");
    const [datetime, setDatetime] = useState<Date>(new Date());
    const [timeSpec, setTimeSpec] = useState<TimeSpecType>("departure");
    const [vias, setVias] = useState<ViaListType>(["", "", ""]);

    const route: RouteType = {
        index: index,
        setIndex: setIndex,
        origin: origin,
        setOrigin: setOrigin,
        destination: destination,
        setDestination: setDestination,
        datetime: datetime,
        setDatetime: setDatetime,
        timeSpec: timeSpec,
        setTimeSpec: setTimeSpec,
        vias: vias,
        setVias: setVias,
    };

    const [routes, setRoutes] = useState<RouteType[]>(new Array<RouteType>(NUM_ROUTES).fill(route));

    const [modes, setModes] = useState<modesType>({
        al: true,
        shin: true,
        ex: true,
        hb: true,
        lb: true,
        sr: true,
    });

    const [speed, setSpeed] = useState<number | null>(null);
    const [order, setOrder] = useState<number | null>(null);
    const options = {
        modes: modes,
        setModes: setModes,
        speed: speed,
        setSpeed: setSpeed,
        order: order,
        setOrder: setOrder,
    };

    const query: QueryType = {
        viaCount: viaCount,
        setViaCount: setViaCount,
        routes: routes,
        setRoutes: setRoutes,
        options: options,
    };

    const [routeCount, setRouteCount] = useState<number>(1);

    const handleSubmit= (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.target);  // Test
        console.log(routeCount, query);  // Test

        const response = axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/", query)
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Form query={query} routeCount={routeCount} setRouteCount={setRouteCount} handleSubmit={handleSubmit}/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

`Form.tsx`

```tsx
import { useState } from "react";
import Route from "./Route";
import Option from "./Option";
import { QueryType } from "../types";
import { NUM_ROUTES } from "../consts";


type FormPropsType = {
    query: QueryType,
    routeCount: number, 
    setRouteCount: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>,
    handleSubmit: (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => void,
}

const Form = ({ query, routeCount, setRouteCount, handleSubmit }: FormPropsType) => {
    const [viaCount, setViaCount] = useState<number>(0);

    return (
        <form id="search" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <ul className="routes">
                {
                    Array.from({length: routeCount}, (_, index) => {
                        return (
                            <li key={index}>
                                <Route viaCount={viaCount} setViaCount={setViaCount} index={index} route={query.routes[index]} handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />
                            </li>
                        );
                    })
                }
            </ul>

            <button type="button" onClick={() => setRouteCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)} disabled={routeCount >= NUM_ROUTES}>経路を追加</button>

            <button form="search" type="submit">検索</button>
        </form>
    );
};

export default Form;
```

`Route.tsx`

```tsx
import Datetime from "react-datetime";
import ja  from "moment";
import { RoutePropsType, TimeSpecType } from "../types";

type radioOptionType = {
    value: TimeSpecType,
    text: string,
}

const Route = ({ viaCount, setViaCount, index, route, handleSubmit }: RoutePropsType) => {
    const radioOptions: radioOptionType[] = [
        {value: "departure", text: "出発"}, 
        {value: "arrival", text: "到着"}, 
        {value: "first", text: "始発"}, 
        {value: "last", text: "終電"}, 
        {value: "none", text: "指定なし"}, 
    ];

    const toISOStringInJpTime = (datetime: Date): string => {
        let str: string = datetime.toLocaleString("ja", { timeZone: 'Asia/Tokyo' }).replaceAll("/", "-").replace(" ", "T");
        str = str.slice(0, 16);  // Remove seconds at the end
        return str
    };
    
    console.log(route);  // Test

    return (
        <div className="route">
            <input type="text" name="origin" placeholder="出発駅・バス停・施設" onChange={e => route.setOrigin(e.target.value)} />
            <input type="text" name="destination" placeholder="到着駅・バス停・施設" onChange={e => route.setDestination(e.target.value)} />
            <input type="datetime-local" name="datetime" value={toISOStringInJpTime(route.datetime)} onChange={e => route.setDatetime(new Date(e.target.value))} />
            
            <div className="radio-container">
            {radioOptions.map((option) => (
                    <label key={option.value}>
                        <input
                            type="radio"
                            value={option.value}
                            name={"time-spec-" + index}
                            onChange={() => route.setTimeSpec(option.value)}
                            checked={option.value === "departure"}
                        />
                        {option.text}
                    </label>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Route;
```

`types.ts`

```tsx
export type modesType = {
    al: boolean,
    shin: boolean,
    ex: boolean,
    hb: boolean,
    lb: boolean,
    sr: boolean,
}

export type FormType = {
    viaCount: number, 
    setViaCount: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>,
    query: QueryType,
}

export type TimeSpecType = "departure" | "arrival" | "first" | "last" | "none"

export type ViaType = string | undefined

export type ViaListType = ViaType[]

export type ViaPropsType = {
    viaCount: number, 
    setViaCount: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>, 
    vias: ViaListType,
    setVias: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<ViaListType>>
}

export type RouteType = {
    index: number | null,
    setIndex: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number | null>>
    origin: string,
    setOrigin: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>,
    destination: string,
    setDestination: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>,
    datetime: Date,
    setDatetime: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Date>>,
    timeSpec: TimeSpecType,
    setTimeSpec: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<TimeSpecType>>,
    vias: ViaListType,
    setVias: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<ViaListType>>,
}

export type optionsType = {
    modes: modesType,
    setModes: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<modesType>>,
    speed: number | null,
    setSpeed: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number | null>>,
    order: number | null,
    setOrder: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number | null>>,
}

export type QueryType = {
    viaCount: number,
    setViaCount: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>,
    routes: RouteType[],
    setRoutes: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<RouteType[]>>,
    options: optionsType,
}

export type FormPropsType = {
    viaCount: number, 
    setViaCount: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>,
    query: QueryType,
    handleSubmit: (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => void,
}

export type RoutePropsType ={
    viaCount: number
    setViaCount: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>,
    index: number | null,
    route: RouteType,
    handleSubmit: (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => void,
}
```

`consts.ts`

```tsx
export const NUM_ROUTES: number = 5;
export const NUM_VIAS: number = 3;
```

今回の質問に関係ないと思われる部分は省略しました。

## コンソールの表示

```
{viaCount: 0, routes: Array(5), options: {…}, setViaCount: ƒ, setRoutes: ƒ}
options
: 
{modes: {…}, speed: null, order: null, setModes: ƒ, setSpeed: ƒ, …}
routes
: 
Array(5)
0
: 
{index: null, origin: '', destination: '', setIndex: ƒ, setOrigin: ƒ, …}
1
: 
{index: null, origin: '', destination: '', setIndex: ƒ, setOrigin: ƒ, …}
2
: 
{index: null, origin: '', destination: '', setIndex: ƒ, setOrigin: ƒ, …}
3
: 
{index: null, origin: '', destination: '', setIndex: ƒ, setOrigin: ƒ, …}
4
: 
{index: null, origin: '', destination: '', setIndex: ƒ, setOrigin: ƒ, …}
length
: 
5
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
setRoutes
: 
ƒ ()
setViaCount
: 
ƒ ()
viaCount
: 
0
```

`query`の中の配列`routes`内の値（`origin`など）が更新されるよう意図していますが、されませんでした。

## その他

`npm`の`create-react-app`を使って雛形を作り、そこから上記コードを書きました。
よろしくお願いいたします。